# How can I call "Refresh Materialized View" programatically in postgresql/timescaledb

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a test suite that runs concurrently.  In my testing I have a method called `refresh_aggregrates` that fundamentally calls `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` on my views.

I am having an issue when they happen in parallel i am getting some weird tuples updated concurrently errors.

To fix, I envisioned creating a procedure or a function that would get an [advisory_lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS), then call the refreshes (so the calls will not interrupt themselves)

Note: I am on pg server 12 (timescale 1.7): (also tested on 11.6, Timescale 1.6)

But when I tried to do this I got: "REFRESH cannot be executed from a function".

^--- Is there a way around this? with sql/plpgsql ?

---

My current function ...

```
create or replace procedure refresh_aggregates()
language plpgsql
as $$
    begin
        perform pg_advisory_lock(124);
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_events_view';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW weekly_events_view';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_customer_user_events';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW weekly_customer_user_events';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_assessments_view';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW weekly_assessments_view';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW active_user_metrics_by_day';
        execute 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW wau_mau_weekly_customer_insights';
        perform pg_advisory_unlock(124);
    end;
$$;

call refresh_aggregates();
```

and results in ...

```
success.public> call refresh_aggregates()
[2020-05-14 15:54:34] [25001] ERROR: REFRESH cannot be executed from a function
[2020-05-14 15:54:34] Where: SQL statement "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_events_view"
[2020-05-14 15:54:34] PL/pgSQL function refresh_aggregates() line 4 at EXECUTE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using PostgreSQL 11 or 12, you can use a stored procedure.

For example:

```
create or replace procedure rmv()
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
 execute 'refresh materialized view my_mv';
end;
$$;
```

I have also tested following function:

```
create or replace function frmv()
returns boolean 
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
 refresh materialized view mv;
 return true;
end;
$$;
```

It does not throw any error and works:

```
select frmv();
 frmv 
------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: curious why does it work with `execute` and not normal syntax

Comment: Actually it also work without EXECUTE in a procedure in PG 12.

Comment: In my environment I can also use a function: I don't understand why you have an error.

Comment: YIKES -- I tried the method and it didn't work for me.  (updating the question with more details)

Comment: I cannot reproduce with PG 12.2 even when calling function in a transaction. I've found in source code origin of the error message in `src/backend/access/transam/xact.c` function  `PreventInTransactionBlock`: but still not clear.

Comment: Maybe caused by VACUUM ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213923/discussion-between-jonathan-and-pifor).